# Почему в слове «свиной» пишется одна Н?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прилагательные, нн

Это относительное прилагательное (не притяжательное, как «фазаний»), производное от существительного.
По логике должно быть две Н, как в слове «осенний» — корень на Н + суффикс Н.
По какому правилу пишется «свиной»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По какому *правилу*? По принадлежности к ряду *исключений*: к основе (свин-), оканчивающейся на *-н*, **не** добавляется суффикс *-н-*. Розенталь приводит такой ряд:

> Запомните: прилагательные *багряный, пряный, пьяный, рдяный, румяный, ветреный (но: безветренный), зелёный, юный, **свиной*** пишутся с одним **н**.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3246

Пара *ветреный/безветренный* добавлена Розенталем как исключение по другому признаку: в слове *ветреный* по общему правилу был бы суффикс **-енн**.

Answer (score 2):

*Свиной* — производное от слова *Свин* — в 1-м знач. — зоол. самец свиньи. Существительное, одушевлённое, мужской род, 2-е склонение (тип склонения 1a по классификации А.А. Зализняка); прилагательные: свиной, свинский, свинячий. Существует группа фамилий, образованных от основы свин- (Свиненков, Свинин, Свининых, Свинков, Свиницын, Свинов, Свинухов, Свинарев, Свиногонов, Свинолобов, Свинопасов).

Прилагательное *свиной* (*-ая*, *-ые*) содержит только 2 морфемы: корень *свин* (он же — основа слова) и окончание -ой.

С существительным *Осень* (неодушевлённое, женский род, 3-е склонение) сопоставлять не имеет смысла.