# Говядинное/говядиное

Tags: орфография, лексика, прилагательные

Как правильно?

1. Говядинное мясо.
2. Говядиное мясо.

Comment: Корововое правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Провела, можно сказать, расследование — обсмотрела статьи словаря Даля, касающиеся возможных прилагательных от самых распространенных "мясных" животных.

Нашлось вот что:
свинья — [свининный/свининый](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475212/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9);
баран — баранов, бараний, барановый;
олень — олений, оленистый;
заяц — зайчиный, заячий, зайчистый;
говядо (бык, вол, корова) — **говяжий**;
теля (теленок) — телятин, теляткин, телков, телкин, телушкин, телячий, теленочий, телочий, телушачий;
конь — конев, коневий, конячий, конский, кониный, коневый, коневатый, конястый;
кролик — кроликовый, кроличий;
лось — лосий, лосиный, лосячий. Лосина, лосица ж. лосиная кожа, обычно в виде замши. **Лосинный** из лосины сделанный.

Из Википедии:

> Говя́дина, говяжье мясо — мясо домашних коров и быков (волов). Мясо молодняка называется телятина. В западноевропейской кулинарии строго различают мясо коров, быков и волов. В России это **общее** понятие.

Думаю, что именно поэтому в языке и нет слова "говядинный".

Прилагательное [**телятинный**](https://etymolog.ruslang.ru/doc/xi-xvii_29.pdf) нашлось в "Словаре русского языка XI–XVII веков (стр. 284):
**1.** Относящийся к телятине (телячьей коже).
**2.** Сделанный из телячьей кожи.

А прилагательное [**конинный**](https://slovar-russkogo-yazyka-xviii-v.slovaronline.com/22996-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — в «Словаре русского языка XVIII в.»:
**1.** Отн. к коню, коням; конский.
**2.** Отн. к конине, конской шкуре.

Comment: Но есть же правило, по которому, несмотря на суффикс *-ин-*, пишется два *н*. Это, по-моему, из-за *н* на конце корня слова происходит (*машина – машинный*). Но почему тогда *свин – свиной*?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  "происходит (машина – машинный). Но почему тогда свин – свиной?" - это, кстати говоря, лучше вопрос, чем про говядинный.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр "Но почему тогда *свин – свиной*?" Вот, дружище, информация на нашем сайте: Почему в слове «свиной» пишется одна Н? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464262/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9d)