# Вопрос от Леопольда "про суффикс -ИН" и удвоение Н в прилагательных, образованных от существительных

Tags: грамматика, суффиксы

Оригинально это звучало так, как комментарий к вопросу про ["говяденное"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475378/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5). Мне показалось это интересным, и я решил сделать из этого отдельный вопрос.

> - Но есть же правило, по которому, несмотря на суффикс -ин-, пишется два н. Это, по-моему, из-за н на конце корня слова происходит (машина – машинный). Но почему тогда свин – свиной? Леопольд.

Answer (score 1):

```
Но почему тогда свин – свиной?
```

С одной буквой Н пишутся отымённые прилагательные с основой на Н и с нулевым суффиксом (сравнить: золото – золотой): ***ворон – вороной, один – единый, свинья – свиной*** (усечение основы сущ. на звук Й).

Comment: мне все-таки кажется свин-свиной. И золото - средний род, там вообще все не так.

Comment: В языке существует такая модель словообразования,  И для слова "свинья" была выбрана именно такая модель. А почему –   это другой вопрос. К примерыу фонетика слова здесь имеет значение.

Comment: Либо вообще свинья - это заимствование от швайн и тп.

Comment: Вряд ли  это будет учитываться.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но у меня есть соображения, что "свиной" и "говяжий" - это притяжательный прилагательные отвечающие на вопрос чей? - чьё мясо, мясо свиньи, свиное, мясо говедо(?) - *говежье* или говяжье, говядина.

Удвоение Н происходит в прилагательных, но не притяжательных?

Машина в свою очередь неодушевленное, образовать от него притяжательное вряд ли получится - машиный, машинин?

ИН - суффикс как раз для образования притяжательных.

Жена - женин, Ваня - ванин, Дима-димин, кура - куриный, мать - материн.

Однако это только для слов оканчивающихся на а-я, ь и тп.

Потому что Сергей-сергеев, бык - бычий и тп.

Кроме того притяжательные могут образовываться с помощью СК - женский, княжеский(и вроде есть форма княжин, потом что князь).

Ну и других суффиксов, в том числе и просто Н.

А вот удвоение происходит при создании от основы не притяжательного прилагательного:

Машина - машин(ин это не суффикс, по крайней мере не очевидный, так как хотя и корень meh-мех/маш, но ин входит в основу) - машин+ный.

Субпродукты(отдельные части) - мясо, перья и тд - происходят от притяжательных прилагательных. Поэтому говяденное(? средний род?) - это вообще мимо. Как и сви́нное(?).

Хотя в ряде случаем о вещах сделанных из "материала от" может происходить удвоение Н, как лосиный - лоси́нный. Но это редкость.

Про вещи же сделанные машинами на заводе говорят заводСКой - то есть ск, притяжательное прилагательное. Завод - это неодушевленное, если это здание, а если завод - это группа людей, то это уже одушевленное и можно образовать притяжательное. Заводской, цеховой или, кстати, цеховской - цехский не говорят, но в целом это не сильно режет слух, не так, как говяденное.

Кстати, притяжательное от маш-мех - механический. А машина - это именно неодушевленный объект. И возможно, машина изначально, это вообще прилагательное от мех образованное уже, просто впоследствии ставшее существительным.

Бывают еще вещи, но одушевленные - кукла-кульный, не объекты, не приборы, не инструменты.

Но может я что-то упускаю.

Comment: Орфографический словарь РАН: лосиный (от лось).  А разве раньше писали с одной Н?   Еще: ЛОСИНА, -ы; ж. 1. Выделанная лосиная или оленья кожа. 2. Лосиное мясо. Варить лосину. Кусок лосины.  Еще: лосинный (от лосина и лосины)

Comment: есть лосиный, а есть лосинный - сделанный из шкуры лося или что-то такое. Там Римма Михайловна писала, по ссылке, это не я выдумал), она брала из источников. Кожа да, а сделанный из лосиного +Н

Comment: Много вариантов про лося)  И все есть в словаре.  Хороший источник. И вопрос хороший...

Comment: Свиной – не притяжательное прилагательное, иначе было бы: свиньего. А слова "свининного"  таки нет.

Comment: Ну никто не говорит, что их не может быть несколько. Есть женин, а есть женский.  Есть свиной, есть свинский. Свиной как мой? Может подвид притяжательного?

Comment: Да, но прилагательные бывают разные: относительные, качественные, притяжательные.  Свиной - относительное прилагательное, это видно по спряжению.

Comment: Ну может я путаю что-то тоже) но я это так пока понимаю) я как нейросеть - еще не научился) князь - княжий. Это притяжательное или нет? или какое?

Comment: По форме притяжательное, так склоняется: княжьего.  А значение нужно уточнять.  Притяж. значение может переходить в относительное.  А вот еще слова с одной Н: тюлень – тюлений, баран – бараний, олень – олений. Можно из них мясо сделать и съесть?

Comment: Ну как сказать. Олений - оленьего, кошачий - кошачьего. Но не кошачный и не оленинный). О, я о том же подумал). Вообще это так сложно, куча слов, а окончания разные: свинья - свиной, олень - олений, говядина - говяжий,  кошка - кошачий. Кот - котовый).

Comment: А тогда что вы от свиньи хотите, она не хуже других. Пусть будет свинье мясо. Надо с этим серьезно разобраться)

Comment: Свинье не получится, потому что уже есть свиньЕ - дательный падеж. Но теоретически, наверное, так тоже понятно будет, в разговорной речи, не удивлюсь если свИнье говорят в деревне.

Comment: Как будто у нас мало слов, которые отличаются ударением. При чем тут деревня? Может, раньше была такая форма?  Надо историю слов смотреть.

Comment: Не могу посмотреть.  Могу пофантазировать: дело в том, что вообще суффикс ин - это про принадлежность определенного качества, индивид или субъект обладающий качеством, подчиненный качеству. Ви - это крик животного, с ви - визг, свин - свиной. Город - городить-огороженный - горожанин(городской субъект),  русь-рус - русин(субъект русского права), мужик - мужчина(обладающий мужественностью, субъект мужественности). Евреи любят фамилии на ин, может подчеркивающие их субъектность, а не рабское-крестьянское происхождение? Крест-крестьянство-крестьянин.

Comment: Смородина - обладающая смородом, запахом, листья пахнут, калина - обладающая краснотой, от калить.

Comment: Хотя не качества, а скорее чего-то большего. Сви́нье нет, возможно потому что это производное от свин, а не от свинья. Как хряк, хрюша.